# Vagrant up (with Ansible) problems. Failed to boot the virtual machine

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh, virtualization

I'm using ubuntu 15.04, and i wanted to install  vagrant with ansible. 
When i vagrant up i get the following error message:

[This is my vagrant file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TfqP.png)

==> default: Successfully added box 'ubuntu/vivid64' (v20151219.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!

==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/vivid64'...

==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...

==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/vivid64' is up to date...

==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant-ansible_default_1451749958531_44597

==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...

==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...

```
default: Adapter 1: nat
```

==> default: Forwarding ports...

```
default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
```

==> default: Booting VM...

==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.
If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.****

I installed ansible with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ansible
```

I used this link to set up my vagrant and playbook.yml file:

https://adamcod.es/2014/09/23/vagrant-ansible-quickstart-tutorial.html

Comment: someone please help

Answer (score 0):

If someone had similar problem.

Do next:

**install NFS kernel**

[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-14-04]

Go to [phansible.com](http://phansible.com/) and create configuration for you PHP project, download and vagrant up......

Comment: download - download configuration that you made on phansible.com